# JavaScript: get the sender element

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have this code:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("hex");
     
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
{
    x[i].addEventListener("click", myFunction);
}
```

To attach onclick dynamically. My question is `myFunction` how to get the clicked element?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let `myFunction` take in an argument (call it `event`). `event.target` is then the clicked element:

```
function myFunction(event) {
    var clickedElement = event.target;
    // Do important stuff with clickedElement.
}
```